# Pass Additional ViewData to DisplayFor Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewdata, display-templates

I want to pass an object `Model.AvailableVerticalType` along with the
`expression` and `templateName` in the call to the HTML Helper `DisplayFor`.
Without passing the object, the [`DisplayFor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) syntax looks like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(o => offer, MVC.Shared.Views.DisplayTemplates.OfferDetail)
```

The `OfferDetail` template accepts an object of the type `Offer` only:

```
@model DGS.DGSAPI.UI.BusinessModels.Offer
```

So I need a way to send the `AvailableVerticleType` through the `ViewData`. Is it possible? What would be the syntax for passing `ViewData` in `DisplayFor()`?

Comment: Is the object part of your model, or have you added in using `ViewBag` of `ViewData` in the GET method? Note that its [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.String,System.Object%29) that you want

Comment: `Model.AvailableVerticalType` is part of the model

Comment: To pass it you would use `@Html.DisplayFor(o => offer, MVC.Shared.Views.DisplayTemplates.OfferDetail, new { data = Model.AvailableVerticalType } )` and then in the template you can access it using `(yourType)ViewData["data"]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by user3559349, you can pass an anonymous object into the DisplayFor() method and that get's to be a part of the ViewData dictionary.

In your view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(o => offer, "OfferDetail", new {AvailableVerticalType = Model.AvailableVerticalType }
```

In your OfferDetail template:

```
(AvailableVerticalType)ViewData["AvailableVerticalType"]
```

You could also just create a partial view that has a model declared for the AvailableVerticalType and reference that in your main view.

> @model AvailableVerticalType

Answer (score 2):

You pass it in `ViewDataDictionary`, example below:

```
// optional: if you don't want to use "AdditionalData" magic string
public static class ViewDataKeys
{
    public const string AdditionalData = "AdditionalData";
}
```

We can use the [2nd overload](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DisplayExtensions.cs) of `DisplayFor` and pass the additional data in `ViewDataDictionary`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyModel, new ViewDataDictionary { { ViewDataKeys.AdditionalData, "additional-value" } })
```

And in your `DisplayFor` template you can access the `ViewDataDictionary` like this:

```
@{
    string additionalData = ViewData[ViewDataKeys.AdditionalData];

    /*
     * if you need to cast the data type:
     * var additionalData = (AdditionalDataType)ViewData[ViewDataKeys.AdditionalData];
     */
}
```

---

You can also pass multiple additional data, for example:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyModel, new ViewDataDictionary { 
    { ViewDataKeys.AdditionalData1, "additional-value1" },
    { ViewDataKeys.AdditionalData2, "additional-value2" }
})
```

*Keeping in mind that it is always better to pass the data in a Model.*

Comment: To me, this is a bit of an XY problem, which the last line of your question really gets to the heart of. The OP is asking about the `ViewData` because they don't know _how_ to pass the data as part of their _model_. Given that, is there a way to extend the model while still relying the expression bindings necessary for the `DisplayFor()` template to properly assess e.g. validation attributes on the original target property? (I'm not certain there is, which thus necessitates the use of `ViewData`.)